# CoreBluetooth "willRestoreState" - what exactly should be done there?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbcentralmanager

I'm developing an application that needs to continuously run and track some peripheral characteristic.

All works fine in foreground.
It also works in background, but I'm not sure that I do it correctly.

I red many posts about state restoration and implementing `willRestoreState`, but many of them don't explicit tells you what to do when this method getting called.

The process that I'm making goes like this:

I'm creating a central manager using

```
myCentralManager =
        [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil
         options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:
         @"myCentralManagerIdentifier" }];
```

From here I'm doing the **regular flow** of:
Waiting for central manager to get powered on (centralManagerDidUpdateState) -> Scan for my peripheral -> Connect to it -> Discover service -> Discover characteristic -> Subscribe to the charactristic -> Reading data

Then I kill my app using

```
kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
```

I'm waiting a couple of seconds, and then starts advertising again from my peripheral.

Then I can see that the process is coming back to life, and my logs show that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in AppDelegate is getting called.

I then restore the central manager like this:

```
 NSArray *identifiers = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey];

   if (identifiers && identifiers.count > 0) {
        _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                               queue:nil
                                                             options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:[identifiers objectAtIndex:0]}];
    }
```

I can also see that `willRestoreState` and `centralManagerDidUpdateState` are getting called.

Here's where I'm lost. 
What should I do next?  If I'm keep doing the regular flow (which I described above, All seems to work fine - and in the same way as above.

But - Am I doing the right thing?

Should I do something in `willRestoreState`?
If yes, what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you figure out the answer to this? In which delegate method what work should be done?

Answer (score 5):

basically you are handed back the peripheral which is already connected - you should save a reference to it and set yourself its delegate. this is my code, it is pretty straight forward:

```
   - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central willRestoreState:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)dict
 {
      //get the handle to the peripheral already connected by the os and set ourselves as the delegate
      NSArray *peripherals = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey];
      if (peripherals.count > 0){
        CBPeripheral* pr = peripherals[0];
        // Set peripheral required values and start discovering services
        [pr setDelegate:self];
        [pr readRSSI];
        [pr discoverServices:nil];
      }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? If I do that I get these errors:
```
API MISUSE: <CBPeripheral: 0x17ef9ef0, identifier = 15BC8CD9-9DC8-3F8C-7B77-765204E74B4B, name = S96906d34cfdcdc65C, mtu = 23, state = connecting> can only accept commands while in the connected state
API MISUSE: <CBCentralManager: 0x17d43060> can only accept this command while in the powered on state
```